# Allocating Memory for a string

Tags: c

I try to allocate memory , store a string then print it but I think it didn't work.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
int main()
{
    char* allochere;
    allochere = malloc(sizeof(char));
    *allochere = "Hello";
    printf("%s",allochere);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) "sizeof(char)" is always 1.  You don't need it, you don't want it.  Specify an *ACTUAL* length instead.  2) The length for "Hello" would be 6: H, e, l, l, o, \0: `allochere = malloc(6);` 3) Use `strcpy()` to copy "Hello" into allochere.  A simple assignment just sets the pointer value, not the contents of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment to `*allochere` only assigns a value to the first character of the uninitialized string. The value assigned is nonsensical to boot, since the right-hand side of the assignment is a pointer. (If you turn on compilation warnings, the compiler will warn you of problems with such an assignment.)

To correctly initialize the string, you need to call `strcpy` to copy the string:

```
strcpy(allochere, "Hello");
```

Also, you need to allocate `allochere` with the correct size to hold the string you intend to put there:

```
allochere = malloc(strlen("Hello") + 1);
```

Comment: Correct me please if I'm wrong : *allochere is a dereferenced pointer to char ... allochere is a pointer to the allocated memory ... &allochere is the address of allochere !

Answer (score 2):

There are several mistakes here.

First of all, you should know that C-strings end with **a zero byte**. Thanks to this, you don't have to store string's length, you're just saying "here's the end of my string" using the zero byte.

Secondly, you call `malloc()` in a wrong way. If you want to allocate memory for an N-letter string, you should write `malloc(N + 1);` (+1 because the zero byte has to have its cell, too).

Lastly, you should use a function like `strcpy` to copy the string to its destination. In this case, you should call `strcpy(allochere, "Hello")`.

Your code should look like this:

```
char* allochere;
allochere = malloc(6*sizeof(char));
strcpy(allochere, "Hello");
printf("%s", allochere);

...

// don't forget to deallocate the memory
free(allochere);
```

Comment: "you should write `(char*)malloc(N + 1);`" No. You should write `malloc(N + 1);`" without the error-hiding `(char*)`.

Comment: There is one more potential mistake.  The allocated memory is not explicitly free()d after use, so there is a potential for a memory leak, expecially if this code is copied somewhere else.  While this is OK in this example - it is implicitly free()d when main() returns - it is bad practice in general and any static analyser worth its salt should flag it.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, you're right, I'll add to make the example complete.

Answer (score 2):

That code doesn't make any sense.

```
char *allochere;
```

'allochere' is a pointer to a char, in other words, a string.

```
allochere = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Now you allocate a single character, and point 'allochere' to that. BTW, `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

```
*allochere = "Hello";
```

Now you set the first char of 'allochere' to a 'const char *', a compiler would barf here. Now allochere points to random data, not a string.

Let's see some alternatives that work.

```
char *allochere;
allochere = "Hello";
printf("%s", allochere);

char *allochere;
allochere = strdup("Hello");
printf("%s", allochere);

char *allochere;
allochere = malloc(strlen("Hello") + 1);
strcpy(allochere, "Hello");
printf("%s", allochere);
```

Comment: Please mention that strdup() contains an implicit malloc().  The returned char* must be free()d, just like any other heap-allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allocating enough memory to hold the word "Hello" - you need to allocate space for 5 chars plus the terminating byte, so you should replace the malloc call with:

```
allochere = malloc(6);
```

You can't assign a string literal to allochere because you will miss the pointer to the allocated memory. Instead, after allocating enough space, use strcpy:

```
strcpy(allochere, "Hello");
```

Comment: Side note: sizeof(char) is always 1; malloc(sizeof(char)) is the same as malloc(1).

Comment: Why do you recommend the casting of `malloc()`'s return value? It is common sense that it is bad.

Comment: Good point. I don't exactly recommend it, it's just the force of habit. I'll just remove it from my code sample, as it is clearly not good advice. Thanks for the heads up ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>

int main()
{
    char* allochere;

    allochere = malloc(strlen("Hello") + 1);

    strcpy(allochere, "Hello");
    printf("%s\n", allochere);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why `#include <windows.h>`?

Comment: Under unix/linux/bsd systems, we would normally include <stdlib.h> to pick up declaration for malloc.  With windows, all bets are off.  It does things 'differently'.  I just assumed, perhaps incorrectly, that <windows.h> is where malloc is declared.

Comment: The OP didn't mention Windows in the question. But even if he did, I don't follow your reasoning. Windows does do many things differently than Unix, but it does support compilers that support standard C functions `malloc`, `strcpy`, and `printf` without resorting to platform-specific headers. Have you tried simply including `<stdlib.h>`?

Comment: The only reason I included <windows.h> is because the original post has it at line 2.  I assumed that the original poster had a good reason for doing it.  I am currently not logged into my windows system and can't verify whether <stdlib.h> will just work.  Can't think of a reason why it wouldn't work if it exists. <windows.h> pulls in a lot of things and it may include <stdlib.h>.

Comment: Since the OP is obviously a beginner, I'd say the assumption is flawed. :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to actually copy the data directly from the string constant `"Hello"` into your allocated space.  However, before we even get there, there are a couple of issues.

1. Make sure you're allocating enough space.

   You are allocating the `sizeof` one character, not enough to hold the entire string (5 characters in "Hello" plus one more for the null terminator).  You can do this with

   ```
   allochere = malloc(6);
   ```

   or use the common convention of

   ```
   allochere = malloc(strlen("Hello") + 1);
   ```

   To be more clear about the size and purpose you're allocating the memory for.
2. You need to copy the data because string assignment doesn't understand exactly what you're trying to do.  By doing

   ```
   *allochere = "Hello";
   ```

   You're actually assigning the value at `allochere` to be the address of `"Hello"`.  If instead you had done this:

   ```
   allochere = "Hello";
   ```

   That might actually work (on some systems -- I'm not sure and haven't tested it), but that's because you are assigning and address to an address.

   However, you are `malloc`ing data which means you want to copy the data.  Thus, you will want to use something like `strcpy` to copy from the location into your allocated string.  Hence:

   ```
   strcpy(allochere, "Hello");
   ```
3. The last problem is going to be actually seeing the output.  Because you're using `printf`, you will need to flush the data to the screen.  `printf` will automatically flush the data if you have a newline (`'\n'`) character, but you could also use `fflush()`.